# checking constructor arguments in mockito' verify method

Tags: mockito

How to check that `compareTo` method will be invoked with this argument `new ComparableVersion("1"))`

```
  verify(comparableVersion).compareTo(any(ComparableVersion.class));
```

Now I use `any` - this is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement a proper `equals` method in your class, you can use the `eq` matcher. It will not verify your constructor, but it will verify against an object that has been initialized to a known state.

Comment: If you have a proper `equals` method in your class, you don't need the `eq` matcher at all.  Just pass the value that you want to compare it to directly, for example `verify(comparableVersion).compareTo(new ComparableVersion("1"));` - this will use your `equals` to compare the actual value to `new ComparableVersions("1")`.

Comment: That's true, @DavidWallace. `eq` is actually not needed in this case at all.